# Add escape character for ctrl-char in a json string

Tags: json, jsondecoder

I am trying to json decode a string but I am getting an error as:

```
 "message":"error while converting json to class","level":"ERROR","level_value":40000,"stack_trace":"com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 31)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string value\n at [Source: { \"key\": \"abc No.\u001F\u001F\u001F\u001F\u001F\u001F\u001F\u001F\u001F\u001F\u001F\u001F\u001F\u001F\u001F\u001F\u001F\u001F\u001F\u001F\u001F\u001F\u001F\u001F\u001F\u001F\u001F\u001F\u001F\u001F\u001F\u001F\u001F\u001F 106,xyz}
```

I am suspecting that there might be a ctrl-char character(/n) in the json. I want to know how add the extra escape character wherever this ctrl-char might be present, so that my code doesn't break while decoding the json.

**Json Decode code:**

```
public static Object jsonDecode(String s, Class c) {
        Object u = null;
        if(s!=null) {
            try {
                u = objectMapper.reader(c)
                        .readValue(s);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("error while converting json to class", e);
            }
        }
        return u;
    }
```